# can receive POST data locally but cannot after deploy

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I POST form data locally to https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm, it can receive message while after I deploy code to server, crm cannot receive the POSt data. I tried to modify name but it doesn't work, no Ajax involved. Can I get some thoughts or possible reason or directions to debug? Really appreciate it.

Code:

```
<div id='crmWebToEntityForm' style='width:400px;margin:auto;'>
   <META HTTP-EQUIV ='content-type' CONTENT='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
   <form action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads2232768000000156067 method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatory()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

     <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
    <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xnQsjsdp' value='beeee37ba331b62bc2d5a5a727bbf3dc004d1b8263b06d3d361af4c37f655a7d'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='zc_gad' id='zc_gad' value=''/>
    <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xmIwtLD' value='800b114061553f1a44679d1d8420bc1c400cd0ab309f22de4cddf8cc8b63feb4'/>
    <input type='text' style='display:none;'  name='actionType' value='TGVhZHM='/>

    <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='returnURL' value='http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.unisol.cn&#x2f;thanks.shtml' /> 
     <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
    <style>
        tr , td { 
            padding:6px;
            border-spacing:0px;
            border-width:0px;
            }
    </style>
    <table style='width:400px;color:black'>
    <tr style='display:none;' ><td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:50%'>Lead Source</td><td style='width:250px;'>
        <select style='width:250px;' name='Lead Source'>
            <option value='-None-'>None</option>

        </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td  style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:200px;'>&#x59d3;&#x540d;<span style='color:red;'>*</span></td><td style='width:250px;' ><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='80' name='Last Name' /></td></tr>

    <tr><td  style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:200px;'>&#x516c;&#x53f8;</td><td style='width:250px;' ><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='100' name='Company' /></td></tr>

    <tr><td  style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:200px;'>&#x7535;&#x8bdd;<span style='color:red;'>*</span></td><td style='width:250px;' ><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='30' name='Mobile' /></td></tr>

    <tr><td  style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:200px;'>Email</td><td style='width:250px;' ><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='100' name='Email' /></td></tr>

    <tr><td  style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:200px;'>&#x9700;&#x6c42;&#x63cf;&#x8ff0;<span style='color:red;'>*</span> </td><td> <textarea name='Description' maxlength='1000' style='width:250px;'>&nbsp;</textarea></td></tr>

    <tr style='display:none;' ><td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:50%'>Product Interest</td><td style='width:250px;'>
        <select style='width:250px;' name='LEADCF1'>
            <option value='-None-'>-None-</option>
        </select></td></tr>

    <tr style='display:none;' ><td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:50%'>Country</td><td style='width:250px;' ><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='30' name='Country' value='China'></input></td></tr>

    <tr><td style='nowrap:nowrap;text-align:left;font-size:15px;font-family:SimHei;width:200px;'>code</td>
        <td><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='80' name='enterdigest' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td></td>
     <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
        <td><a href='javascript:;' onclick='reloadImg()'><img id='imgid' height="50" width="250" border="2" src='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/CaptchaServlet?formId=800b114061553f1a44679d1d8420bc1c400cd0ab309f22de4cddf8cc8b63feb4&grpid=beeee37ba331b62bc2d5a5a727bbf3dc004d1b8263b06d3d361af4c37f655a7d'>
        </a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:center; padding-top:15px;'>
        <input style='font-size:20px;color:#131307' type='submit' value='submit' />          
        <input type='reset' style='font-size:20px;color:#131307' value='reset' />
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
    <script>
      var mndFileds=new Array('Last Name','Mobile','Description');
      var fldLangVal=new Array('name','phone','description');
        var name='';
        var email='';

  /* Do not remove this code. */
      function reloadImg() {
        if(document.getElementById('imgid').src.indexOf('&d') !== -1 ) {
          document.getElementById('imgid').src=document.getElementById('imgid').src.substring(0,document.getElementById('imgid').src.indexOf('&d'))+'&d'+new Date().getTime();
        }  else {
          document.getElementById('imgid').src = document.getElementById('imgid').src+'&d'+new Date().getTime();
         } 
     }

      function checkMandatory() {
        for(i=0;i<mndFileds.length;i++) {
          var fieldObj=document.forms['WebToLeads2232768000000156067'][mndFileds[i]];
          if(fieldObj) {
            if (((fieldObj.value).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length==0) {
             if(fieldObj.type =='file')
                { 
                 alert('Please select a file to upload.'); 
                 fieldObj.focus(); 
                 return false;
                } 
            alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be empty.'); 
              fieldObj.focus();
              return false;
            }  else if(fieldObj.nodeName=='SELECT') {
             if(fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value=='-None-') {
                alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be none.'); 
                fieldObj.focus();
                return false;
               }
            } else if(fieldObj.type =='checkbox'){
             if(fieldObj.checked == false){
                alert('Please accept  '+fldLangVal[i]);
                fieldObj.focus();
                return false;
               } 
             } 
             try {
                 if(fieldObj.name == 'Last Name') {
                name = fieldObj.value;
                }
            } catch (e) {}
            }
        }
         }

</script>
    </form>
  <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
     <iframe name='captchaFrame' style='display:none;'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: your form POST url is `https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm`-> so data will goes to this URL. are you handling code of this URL? I don't think so, because it's a third party URL

Comment: the purpose is to handle data in crm system in this third party URL, I can get the data when POST from local env while cannot from production env

Comment: Open your inspector window and see the network traffic when you hit POST. The zoho server may give you an error message for diagnosis

Comment: Actually I've tried that while there's no error message and network infomation in the inspector which is really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved and it is the zoho-end problem.....